# Kernel summation plot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I'd like to plot out some data in a way that reflects a smoothed summation of the variable of interest.  This is in contrast to a density plot or histogram, which focuses on counts.  `stat_bin` achieves what I'm after (the dashed line below), but doesn't do it with a smoothed kernel.  `geom_density` (red line) has a smooth kernel, but operates on counts, not values.  I've tried adding weights to the density estimate, but that doesn't seem to achieve what I'm after.  A loess or other curve (blue line) fits the individual values across the continuous axis, not a windowed summation.

Any recommendations would be much appreciated!  `ggplot2` solutions preferred.  Thanks in advance!

```
library(ggplot2)
mydf = data.frame(a = sample(1:100, 100, replace = T))
mydf$b = abs(sin((mydf$a)/50*2*pi) + rnorm(100, sd = 0.1))

ggplot(mydf, aes(x = a)) +
    geom_bar(aes(weight = b)) +
    geom_smooth(se = F, aes(y = b), method = "loess", span = 0.3) +
    stat_bin(geom = "line", position = "identity", binwidth = 4, aes(weight = b), lty = 2) +
    geom_density(stat = "identity", aes(y = b), color = "red", size = 1.2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [`ggh4x::stat_rollingkernel()`](https://teunbrand.github.io/ggh4x/articles/Statistics.html#rolling-kernels-1) does what you're looking for. (A disclaimer: I'm the author of ggh4x.)

By default, it uses a rolling gaussian kernel to describe a trend in xy-coordinate data, wherein y-values are weighted by `dnorm(x, mean = kernel_x, sd = bw)`

For this particular example, the default bandwidth does a poor job, but you can adjust the `bw` parameter to fit the data better.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)
#> Warning: package 'ggh4x' was built under R version 4.0.5

set.seed(0)

mydf = data.frame(a = sample(1:100, 100, replace = T))
mydf$b = abs(sin((mydf$a)/50*2*pi) + rnorm(100, sd = 0.1))

ggplot(mydf, aes(x = a)) +
  geom_col(aes(y = b)) +
  geom_smooth(se = F, aes(y = b), method = "loess", span = 0.3) +
  stat_rollingkernel(aes(y = b), bw = 3, colour = "red", size = 1.2)
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-05-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Edit: yes if you multiply the outcome by their weights, you should get something more closely resembling the sum instead of the average.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)
#> Warning: package 'ggh4x' was built under R version 4.0.5

set.seed(0)

mydf = data.frame(a = sample(1:100, 100, replace = T))
mydf$b = abs(sin((mydf$a)/50*2*pi) + rnorm(100, sd = 0.1))

ggplot(mydf, aes(x = a)) +
  geom_col(aes(y = b)) +
  stat_rollingkernel(aes(y = stage(b, y), colour = "weighted"), 
                     bw = 3, size = 1.2) +
  stat_rollingkernel(aes(y = stage(b, y * weight), colour = "unweighted"), 
                     bw = 3, size = 1.2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-05-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks @teunbrand - looks promising, and sounds like what I'm after.  One question: in the data, there are a number of entries at some particular values (e.g. the sum of values at a=89 is over 4, even though each value is just over 1).  ```stat-rollingkernel``` doesn't sum them - it just seems to fit to the mean or max of all values at that location.  I could bin them myself, but this becomes an issue with a continuous x-axis.  Is there any way to make ```stat_rollingkernel``` sum instead of mean/max?  Setting the bandwidth to something very small doesn't help...

Comment: I've put in an edit that might (partially) answer your follow-up question